# Does Accomplishments work in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, launchpad, accomplishments

I've installed Accomplishments in Lubuntu, according to [ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accomplishments/Installing).

I connected it to my Ubuntu One account.
I've registered myself on Launchpad and Ask Ubuntu sites. I added accounts info to Accomplishments and I waited few days but the trophies have not been verified.

So I removed accomplishment and all connected files, which I had found and I've installed it once again. I've configured it once again but it still hasn't verified launchpad and ask Ubuntu trophies.

I found repeated message in Accomplishments' log:

```
2012-08-11 17:37:04+0200 [-] --- Starting Running Scripts ---
2012-08-11 17:37:04+0200 [-] No gnome-session process for user
```

There is no gnome-session in Lubuntu, I think ? So my question is, does it work correctly under Lubuntu?

Comment: I've found ubuntu accomplishments to be horribly buggy.  My solution was to decide something that buggy wasn't worth my time.

Comment: "There is no gnome-session in Lubuntu, I think" well you're using LXDE not Gnome.. so yeah..

Answer (score 2):

That message appears to come from the accomplishments daemon. It uses the gnome-session process to make sure a user is signed on and if so to find the the environment of those users. From that environment it can find the socket address of the session's dbus.

I don't know if there are further dependencies on gnome-session.

I'd say the package just isn't far enough along yet to support non-gnome sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Requirements for Lubuntu 12.04 are: gnomes-games (mahjong/gnomine),gwibber, etc...
If not You'll get this error message:

> Oops, an error ocurred: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not
>   receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did
>   not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply,
>   the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.